"Backshift - ​the changing of a tense when reporting what somebody said." — There is no subject for the verb "reporting". Is it omitted?
cambridge.org:
(1) We don’t use a question mark when reporting wh-questions.
As far as I understand, the dependent clause "reporting wh-questions" doesn't have a subject because the subject is the same as in the main clause: "we". That is, the full sentence will be:
(2) We don’t use a question mark when we are reporting wh-questions.
Therefore, "when" in (1) is a conjunction, right?

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:
(3) Backshift - ​the changing of a tense when reporting what somebody said.
This sentence is different from (1) because there is no subject for the dependent clause "reporting what somebody said" which could be copied from another part of the sentence as it was done with "we" in (2).
Then why is there not a subject after "when" here?
What subject is implied after "when" in (3) and how did you find it out?

What is your (one) question? Please put one question, not three sentences, in your title.

@PaulTanenbaum Sorry, I have a feeling you missed something. The topic is obvious: the absence of subjects after "when". All questions relate to it. And the title has the question "Is it omitted?". Please explain your comment. It's surprising me very much.

@Loviii You ask three different questions in your question. I can guess that the first question is your expression of a supposition you're making as you go, not an actual question. The other two sound like two parts of the same question, but it's still better to phrase it as one question. If not, different answerers will choose different parts to answer. Someone might only answer about whether "when" is a conjunction.

The implied subject is you/we/one, omitted for brevity in dictionary definitions. In the Cambridge example, as you say, it's when we are reporting.... In the Oxford example it could be when you are reporting... ('you' meaning 'people in general') or, more formally, when one is reporting...

The subject is either the same as in the original sentence, as in your (2), and when there isn't a subject, it's the understood subject "one":
(4) Backshift - ​the changing of a tense when one is reporting what somebody said.
